How to interpret a search pattern when using a regex
I am trying to understand this line of code. It is hard for me to interpret the purpose the pattern the author aims to search.
What's the best way to understand this line of code? Or is there a way to print out the search pattern?
found = re.search(r'(mad|fma)\.r[nzmp]\.(ftz\.)?f32', text) is not None

It matches these strings and more:
mad.rn.ftz.f32
fma.rn.ftz.f32
fma.rz.ftz.f32
fma.rm.ftz.f32
fma.rp.ftz.f32
fma.rp.f32
mad.rp.f32


Then, it extracts two groups ():
import re
def _find(s):
    p = r'(mad|fma)\.r[nzmp]\.(ftz\.)?f32'
    f = re.findall(p, s)
    return f


s = """mad.rn.ftz.f32
fma.rn.ftz.f32
fma.rz.ftz.f32
fma.rm.ftz.f32
fma.rp.ftz.f32
fma.rp.f32
mad.rp.f32
"""
print(_find(s))


Prints
[('mad', 'ftz.'), ('fma', 'ftz.'), ('fma', 'ftz.'), ('fma', 'ftz.'), ('fma', 'ftz.'), ('fma', ''), ('mad', '')]

Breakdown:

(mad|fma): means capture these two strings: mad and fma.
\.r[nzmp]: finds the combinations of .r and one of these four characters: nzmp.
\.: simply matches a dot.
(ftz\.)?: means the existence of this group (ftz.) is optional (i.e., ?).
f32: means f32.

